# Allowing paste answer in Moodle essay question

Tags: moodle

As far as I can see, students are not allowed to paste answers in essay type questions. Is there a way for the teacher to configure questions to allow pasting in essay answers?

Just for context:

I want to let students to paste results and code from R or a spreadsheet. I know it works with short answers but I want now to use essay. I also know that if the student clicks the "edit html" button, they can paste text, but format gets ruined - even line breaks.

And as far as I know, using Firefox instead of Chrome allows to paste answers, but from online sources I can find that is not a feature but a bug intended to be solved.

Comment: I've learned that right clicking and selecting "paste text without format". I'm not sure about whether I should delete my question or answer it.

Comment: In the end I answered the question. I hope it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In essay questions "paste" or Ctrl+V don't work from other sources. However, right clicking and selecting "paste text without format" does.

Clicking the "edit html" button and pasting into the html code also works, although it is less likely to be useful.